# Keeping lru_cache results

Tags: python, caching, multiprocessing

I am using lru_cache to reduce computation times (I have millions of iterations of the same steps over a state space grid) but am also using multiprocessing to parallelise since all computations within a batch are independent of each other. So the scheme looks a bit like:

```
get batch (i) of independent computations
split batch (i) into little batchlets, one for each core
calculate each batchlet on each core using `multiprocessing.pool` with lru_cache
merge the results of all the batchlets to get next batch (i+1)
repeat from the beginning with batch (i+1)
```

This in general works nicely, however it's not completely efficient. The way the lru_cache decorator seems to work is that each worker/core in the pool has their own cache in their presumably own designated RAM.
There are two things I would like to improve upon, but I don't know how to facilitate:

1. use a shared cache across all pool workers
2. keep the cache across all batches, maybe in an import export kind of fashion (a lot of the operations are the same for any batch, even though each batch requires the previous batch as input)

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: `functools.lru_cache` is implemented in `c`, so you can't readily change how it works. you will have to implement your own to get these features. Unfortunately this also means it may be difficult (not impossible per-se) to meet the same performance as the stdlib version.

Comment: One of the key concepts of `lru_cache` anyway is that things that haven't come up for a while may get thrown away to conserve memory. If the cache is considered volatile anyway it doesn't make tons of sense to save it to disk in most cases. If you have a limited set of possible inputs, it may make more sense to just save everything (time / space efficiency trade off) and update a file with new entries that show up.

Comment: So that would be just a simple dictionary with the hashed inputs as keys. This dictionary I could then pass through whenever I start the calculations on a new batch, right?

Comment: The calculations I make are not crazy complex, but they are so frequent, that memoization still pays off. This is however only the case because the lookup is so fast. If I share the cache dict, would that increase lookup times? That could make the trade off not worth it in my case.

Comment: Transferring data between child processes is rather slow. It sounds like `lru_cache` may still be as good as it gets. Once the cache is at capacity (assuming the size is limited), the c implementation will probably be faster than anything you'll manage with just a dictionary. If the "startup" time is very important, you might try like you mentioned using a simple dictionary filled with entries from a file.